# Refactor moving average select statement into update statement

Tags: mysql

I have a working select statement that selects me the moving average of 1day_rank

```
SELECT
 *, 
 (SELECT AVG(1day_rank)
  FROM keyword_rank T2
  WHERE (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM keyword_rank T3
           WHERE timestamp BETWEEN T2.timestamp AND T1.timestamp and t3.keyword_id=t2.keyword_id 
      ) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 and T2.keyword_id=T1.keyword_id and (T2.timestamp > T1.timestamp - interval 7 day)
 ) average
FROM keyword_rank T1 where T1.keyword_id=86;
```

I want to refactor this statement to an update statement that will update the result into 7day_rank. But this is not allowed by MY_SQL causing: "Error Code: 1093: You can´t specify target table 'T1' for update in FROM clause"

```
update keyword_rank T1 set T1.7day_rank=
 (
 SELECT
      AVG(1day_rank)
 FROM
      (select * from keyword_rank sub where sub.keyword_id=86) as T2
 WHERE
      (
           SELECT
                COUNT(*)
           FROM
                keyword_rank T3
           WHERE
                timestamp BETWEEN T2.timestamp AND T1.timestamp and t3.keyword_id=86 
      ) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 and (T2.timestamp > T1.timestamp - interval 7 day)
 )
  where T1.keyword_id=86;
```

So i have tried to refactor this statement using a inner join but that creates another error "Error Code: 1054, Unknown column 'T1.timestamp' in 'where clause'"

```
update keyword_rank T1 inner join (
  select AVG(1day_rank) average, timestamp from keyword_rank T2
  where (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM keyword_rank T3
           WHERE timestamp BETWEEN T2.timestamp AND T1.timestamp and t3.keyword_id=86 
      ) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 and T2.keyword_id=86 and (T2.timestamp >   T1.timestamp - interval 7 day)
 ) as TX set T1.7day_rank=TX.average;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the query by taking the whole working select and putting it to the inner join.

```
UPDATE keyword_rank as U
        INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
             T1.keyword_id, T1.timestamp, 
             (SELECT AVG(1day_rank)
             FROM keyword_rank T2
             WHERE (
                       SELECT COUNT(*)
                       FROM keyword_rank T3
                       WHERE timestamp BETWEEN T2.timestamp AND T1.timestamp and t3.keyword_id=T2.keyword_id 
                  ) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 and T2.keyword_id=t1.keyword_id and (T2.timestamp > T1.timestamp - interval 7 day) 
             ) as average
        FROM keyword_rank T1 where T1.keyword_id=86
    ) T on U.keyword_id=T.keyword_id and U.timestamp=T.timestamp
SET 
    U.7day_rank = average;
```

Comment: It feels like there's some redundancy here